# How to make the entire div expandable when clicking on the down arrow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the entire #main-slider container expandable when clicking on the down arrow. a.next-down-chevron, the only two things I want to be shown is the title engineering and the down arrow. I googled but only managed to hide the three containers in the middle, all the carousel arrows and tabs are still showing. My code:

```
 <section id="main-slider" class="no-margin wow fadeInDown">
        <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

          <div class="engineering-section">
            <div class="engineering-section-title title-text text-center">Engineering</div>
              <div class="down-button bounceInDown animated">
                  <a class="next-down-chevron" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
              </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
              <div class="card-container">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card-section">
                    <div class="mdl-card__media">
                      <img src="img/engineer-1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                      <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Enginnering Suite (May 2015)</span>
                      <div class="checksum">
                        <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                      </div>
                    </div><!--end supporting text-->
                    <div class="card_actions">
                       <a class="card-links" href="#">
                         Download Now
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                       </a>
                    </div><!--end card_actions-->
                  </div><!--end card-section-->
                </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="card-section">
                  <div class="mdl-card__media">
                    <img src="img/engineer-2.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                    <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Process Manuals and Process Tools</span>
                    <div class="checksum">
                    <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card_actions">
                     <a class="card-links" href="#">
                       Download Now
                       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                     </a>
                  </div><!--end card_actions-->
                </div><!--end card-section-->
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card-section"> 
                <div class="mdl-card__media">
                  <img src="img/engineer-3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">Aspen License Deployment Assistant</span>
                  <div class="checksum">
                    <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_actions">
                   <a class="card-links" href="#">
                     Download Now
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                   </a>
                </div><!--end card_actions-->
              </div><!--end card-section-->
           </div><!--end col-md-4-->  
        </div><!--end card-container-->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="card-container content-one">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card-section">
                    <div class="mdl-card__media">
                      <img src="img/1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                      <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Enginnering Suite (May 2015)</span>
                      <div class="checksum">
                        <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                      </div>
                    </div><!--end supporting text-->
                    <div class="card_actions">
                       <a class="card-links" href="#">
                         Download Now
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                       </a>
                    </div><!--end card_actions-->
                  </div><!--end card-section-->
                </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="card-section">
                  <div class="mdl-card__media">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                    <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">V8.8 aspenONE Process Manuals and Process Tools</span>
                    <div class="checksum">
                    <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card_actions">
                     <a class="card-links" href="#">
                       Download Now
                       <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                     </a>
                  </div><!--end card_actions-->
                </div><!--end card-section-->
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card-section"> 
                <div class="mdl-card__media">
                  <img src="img/3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <span class="mdl-typography--font-light mdl-typography--subhead">Aspen License Deployment Assistant</span>
                  <div class="checksum">
                    <a class="info_checksum" href="#">Checksum</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_actions">
                   <a class="card-links" href="#">
                     Download Now
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                   </a>
                </div><!--end card_actions-->
              </div><!--end card-section-->
           </div><!--end col-md-4-->  
        </div><!--end card-container-->
      </div>
    </div><!--end engineering-->
  </div>
 </div>

</section>
```

Comment: The code is not precise and very readable. Can you be little more specific? Add a jsfiddle or plunker so that people can work on that and help.

Comment: I see you have the id="main-slider" on a section and your question asks about expanding a div.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/a13qcfLy/

Comment: Right, main slider there is for the carousel slider, but I need the whole section to be expandable.

Comment: You're Engineering Title and your Down arrow are inside your "main-slider". You can't collapse the 'main-slider' div and still show your 'Engineering' title and down arrow. You'll have to pull those out of the collapsed section. If you want it to be between the Carousel and the content below it, those sections will have to wrapped in a separate divs that can be collapsed and expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option if you want to leave the Title and opener in the middle of the div is to have a copy Title and opener outside the div. and Hide those on click and show the main-slider with something like this:

```
$('a.next-down-chevron').click(function(){
    $('#engineering-trigger').hide();
    $('#main-slider').show();
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5pkmoq0/